# Why are braces needed for preprocessor in order to have statement?

Tags: c, inline-assembly, preprocessor

Having this code:

```
#define GREATER(a, b, res) ( \ /* no braces here */
    asm("cmp %1, %2\n\t" \
         "jge 0f\n\t" \
         "movl %1, %0\n\t" \
         "jmp 1f\n" \
         "0:\n\t" \
         "movl %2, %0\n" \
         "1:" \
         : "=r"(res) \
         : "r"(a), "r"(b)); )
```

Error:
`c.c:4:2: error: expected expression before ‘asm’
  asm("cmp %1, %2\n\t" \`

But this one (only changed braces, everything else is left - the code is otherwise correct):

```
#define GREATER(a, b, res) ({ \ /* used braces here - correct */
    asm("cmp %1, %2\n\t" \
         "jge 0f\n\t" \
         "movl %1, %0\n\t" \
         "jmp 1f\n" \
         "0:\n\t" \
         "movl %2, %0\n" \
         "1:" \
         : "=r"(res) \
         : "r"(a), "r"(b)); })
```

Will compile with no error.
But the only changed is added braces. So why are they needed? What does the preprocessor assume to be statement? (If only means being in braces.) I have seen other macro functions declared only in parenthesis (no curly braces), so why this one should have ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preprocessor directives are not involved in this issue. The issues are:

- `asm(…)` is a GCC extension to the C language. GCC treats `asm`, which must be followed by a `;`, as a *statement*.
- Parentheses are parts of expressions. When you write `(…)`, the contents of the parentheses should be an expression. Since `asm` is not an expression, `(asm(…);)` is an error.
- GCC has an extension called [*statement expressions*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), in which `({…})` has a value like an expression but may contain statements. Inside `({…})`, you may put statements inside the braces, and GCC will evaluate them and use the value of the last *expression statement*<sup>1</sup> in them as the value of the `({…})` expression. (The last statement in `({…})` should be an expression statement, as opposed to some other kind of statement, just as a `for` loop.)

Thus `({ asm(…); })` is accepted as an expression.

However, although GCC accepts it, it is violating the statement in GCC’s documentation that “The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon…”. It does not look like your macro is intended to be used as an expression; it puts a result in `res` but does not itself have a value. In this case, you can make it simply a statement by removing the parentheses from your original code:

```
#define GREATER(a, b, res) \
    asm("cmp %1, %2\n\t" \
         "jge 0f\n\t" \
         "movl %1, %0\n\t" \
         "jmp 1f\n" \
         "0:\n\t" \
         "movl %2, %0\n" \
         "1:" \
         : "=r"(res) \
         : "r"(a), "r"(b));
```

Additionally, people often prefer to leave off the final `;` in such macros, because then the macro can be written like a statement when used in source code:

```
GREATER(a, b, res);
```

instead of looking odd to people who are accustomed to statements ending with `;`:

```
GREATER(a, b, res)
```

(Although with the `;` in the definition, you can still write `GREATER(a, b, res);`, but this expands to have `;;`, and that can cause problems, because `if (foo) GREATER(a, b, res); else…` will fail to associate that `else` with that `if` because of the extra `;`.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> A *statement expression* is an expression followed by a `;`.

Comment: Yeah, this macro seems overcomplicated, or like they forgot a `{ ...; res; }` at the end to give the statement-expression a value.

Comment: But's possible to write macro expansion as statement (semicolon), you said it could be written as `GREATER(a,b,res); ...` and will expapand to {...};. How is possible to have semicolon in header macro, and it will expand to body macro?

Answer (score 3):

If you compile the code fragment as posted, you will indeed get an error as the macro is defined as `#define GREATER(a, b, res) ( \ /* no braces here */` and the remainder of the fragment is parsed as a separate line of source code because the `\` is not the last character on the `#define` line.

You should be careful with the comment placement.

More generally, the `asm` statement is not an expression, it is a statement, hence it cannot occur between parentheses. If you wish to use the macro in an expression context, you must convert the statement to an *statement-expression* by surrounding it with `({` and `})`, a gcc extension, just like the `asm` statement.  For the result to be used in an expression context, you must specify the value:

```
/* used braces here - correct */
#define GREATER(a, b, res) ({ \
    asm("cmp %1, %2\n\t" \
         "jge 0f\n\t" \
         "movl %1, %0\n\t" \
         "jmp 1f\n" \
         "0:\n\t" \
         "movl %2, %0\n" \
         "1:" \
         : "=r"(res) \
         : "r"(a), "r"(b)); res; })
```

Finally, the assembly code to compute the greater of `a` and `b` is inefficient. The compiler will likely generate better code from `res = greater(a, b)` with `greater` defined as `static inline int greater(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }`

Comment: Well of course compiler is probably efficient, but that is for "inline assembly" study purposes. Anyway, why is statemen-expression `({})` an extension? Why it is not a native feature of gcc? How else would be done macro function-like expansion, where it is placed in expression `#define somefunc(a,b) (...)`. It should have been featured in gcc as native, because you end up in expression a lot (in preprocessor defining)

Comment: @Herdsman: by *extension*, I mean a feature specific to gcc that is not part of the C Standard. It is native in gcc, unless you instruct it to reject non standard extensions. Paying with inline assembly is not for the faint of heart, have fun learning!